# How to modify a CSS variable in a shared-styles Polymer Element

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

Good evening everyone,

I'd like to know it is possible to modify the value of a CSS variable and if this change would take effect immediately across every polymer element that includes it.

Here is the déclaration of the CSS variables that i'd like to dinamically change :

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<!-- shared styles for all views -->
<dom-module id="shared-styles">
  <template>
    <style>
      :root {
        --apc: #099b34;
        --asc: #4CAF50; /*App Secondary Color*/
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Have a nice evening, thanks

NeitoFR

Edit 1 : I tried the first method given by @d.mares but it doesn't work. 
As you can see on the picture it appears on the element.style part but do not override the host definitions and do not spread across other elements.
[image: As you can see]

Edit 2 : 
by doing some research, I managed to get an error that answer partially my question : 
[image: error css]
So.. It seems that it is not dinamically changeable. I need to find another way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, you would have to call `this.updateStyles` and pass the new values:

```
  this.updateStyles({
    '--apc': 'blue',
    '--as': 'red'
  });
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. I added a new method called on log in that set the new values as you showed. It take effects on the 'element style' but not in the :host and therefore not in the application

Answer (score 0):

For global effect you would need to modify the element that holds the original declaration of the variables.

> CSS Variables are subject to the cascade and inherit their value from
>   their parent.

*From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)*

Comment: I added some observer inside the shared-styles element, where the first declaration is made. I tried a bunch of method to interact and modify CSS rules, none worked.